# How to show events in full calendar in zend framework2?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework2, fullcalendar

I am new in zend and i use full calender for creating events,my events are stored in database but not shown on calender how i show events on calender?
here is my code:

```
<?php
// module/Album/view/album/album/add.phtml:

$title = 'Create New Event';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h3><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h3>
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('event', array(
'action' => 'create',
'id' => $form->get('calendar_id')->getValue()
)));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('event_id'));
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('calendar_id'));
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('author_id'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('description'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('begin'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('end'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>

<?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>

$(function(){
$('*[name=begin]').appendDtpicker({
    "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:00"
}  );
$('*[name=end]').appendDtpicker({
    "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:00"
});
});

<?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd();
```

and here is my events show code:

```
 <?php
$calendar = $this->calendar;

$title = $this->escapeHtml($calendar->title);
$this->headTitle($title);
 ?>

 <h3><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h3>

 <p>Click in the blank space to add a new term, click on your choice to see the detail of y.</p>

 <p>Author Calender:
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($calendar->email) . ' ' . $this->gravatar($this->escapeHtml($calendar->email)); ?>
 </p>

 <p>description: <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($calendar->description); ?></p>

 <p><a href="<?php echo $this->url('calendar');?>">Back to list Calender</a></p>

 <div id="fullcalendar"></div>

 <?php $this->headScript()->captureStart(); ?>

 $(document).ready(function() {
// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
$('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({


    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },

    defaultView: 'month',
    allDaySlot: false,

    events: '<?php echo $this->url('event',array('action'=>'load', 'id' => $this->escapeHtml($calendar->calendar_id)));?>',

    eventDataTransform: function(eventData) {
        eventData.start = new Date(eventData.begin);
        eventData.end = new Date(eventData.end);
        eventData.allDay = false;
        eventData.url = '<?php echo $this->url('event',array('action'=>'show'));?>' + '/' + eventData.event_id;
        return eventData;
    },

    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

        var action = '<?php echo $this->url('event',array('action'=>'create', 'id' => $this->escapeHtml($calendar->calendar_id))) ?>';
        var dateUri = date.getTime() / 1000;
        var allDayUri = allDay ? 1 : 0;

        console.log(action + '/' + dateUri  + '/' + allDayUri);
        window.location = action + '/' + dateUri  + '/' + allDayUri;
    },


});
 });    

 <?php $this->headScript()->captureEnd();
```

and here is my load action of event:

```
 public function loadAction()
    {
        $response = $this->getResponse();

        //if ($request->isPost()) {
            $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
            if ($id) {
                $events = $this->getEventTable()->fetchAllByCalendar($id);
                $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($events));

            }
        //}

        return $response;
    }
```

and here is my show action of calender:

```
public function showAction()
    {
        if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity())
        {
            $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
            if (!$id) {
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('calendar', array(
                    'action' => 'create'
                ));
            }

            $calendar = $this->getCalendarTable()->getCalendar($id);

            return array('calendar' => $calendar);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcuser/login');
        }
    }
```

here is my response:

```
 [{"event_id":"2","calendar_id":"1","author_id":"1","title":"Launch","description":"Launch Break","begin":"2014-03-02 20:00:00","end":"2014-03-31 16:53:00","calendar_title":"Hijri Calender","author_email":"arif.liaqat@yahoo.com"}]
```

how i show events on calender?

Comment: anyone who use full calender in zendframework2?

Comment: You try to feed the calendar with the data from database. That's the issue ? I've never use it with Zf2 but I'm certain data are coming from 'events'. Can you you show us your load action ?

Comment: yes i put my load action code plz see my code

Comment: Why your fetchAll method takes an id ? Your response is not empty ?

Comment: plz give me the solution i want to show events on calender

Comment: no my response is not empty

Comment: but events are not shown on calender

Comment: this is my response [{"event_id":"3","calendar_id":"4","author_id":"2","title":"launch","description":"launch","begin":"2014-04-07 21:00:00","end":"2014-04-17 11:11:00","calendar_title":"launch","author_email":"arsalashfaq@gmail.com"},{"event_id":"4","calendar_id":"4","author_id":"2","title":"Launch","description":"Launch","begin":"2014-04-15 21:00:00","end":"2014-04-24 11:50:00","calendar_title":"launch","author_email":"arsalashfaq@gmail.com"}]

Comment: Debflav give me the solution of shownig events in calender

Comment: Firstly, you should edit your comment to avoid flood. Then, I don't know the answer. It seems that you don't give start, end, allDay keywords to fullCalendar... But I guess your eventDataTransform does it so I've no idea. I suggest you to try debugging with console.log() and see what's print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at the date format you try to pass to new Date function.
You can't create a js Date object with this: `new Date('2014-03-02 20:00:00')`. If you run this in your browser's console it fails. You have to convert it first to a "real" datetime that includes timezone data as well.

so what you have to do is somehow get separated the values of the date string you have and 
`eventData.start = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`

and same thing for

`eventData.end`

Comment: i used your code then this error occur ReferenceError: year is not defined how i remove this error?

Comment: loadaction give me response but not show events on calender

Comment: "get separated the values of the date string you have". It means that you have to assign the values of your date like: year = 2014, month = 3 etc, and after that create a date object by all these separated values. I have not understand exactly the procedure you are following in creating the events so I don't know if you have to do it in php or in javascript. But it is normal that it says "year is not defined" since you never defined it

Comment: eventData.start = new Date(eventData.year, eventData.month, eventData.day, eventData.hours, eventData.minutes, eventData.seconds, eventData.milliseconds);
   eventData.end = new Date(eventData.year, eventData.month, eventData.day, eventData.hours, eventData.minutes, eventData.seconds, eventData.milliseconds); i changed code according to this but events not shown on calender how i show events on calender?

Comment: are you sure that apart from this you also made a change that you extract the year, month, day etc from the date that you have? According to your code, eventData.year, eventData.month etc are not set.

Comment: give me code which you want i include in my code i dont understand what u say

Comment: I have not understand the procedure you are following so it's up to you to decide if you will get these values from php or not. Anyway, assuming that you want to do this in js, do the following in eventDataTransform `eventData.start = new Date(eventData.begin.replace(' ', 'T'));
        eventData.end = new Date(eventData.end.replace(' ', 'T'));`

Comment: TypeError: eventData.begin.replace is not a function when i used your code this error exist